# Pasar informacion de una pagina php a otra

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quiero pasar informacion de una pagina php a otra. El problema es que no lo consigo hacer.

```
$uname=$_POST['username'];

$sql3="SELECT group_id FROM workgroup WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM people WHERE username='mlopez')";
$query3 = $dbh->prepare($sql3);
$query3->execute();
$data = $query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$group_id = $data['group_id'];

<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="<?php echo('welcome.php?user=' . $uname . '&group=' . $group_id);   ?>">
```

Algo debo estar haciendo mal, alguien me puede ayudar?

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero que previamente armes tu URL:

```
<?php
$uname=$_POST['username'];

$sql3="SELECT group_id FROM workgroup WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM people WHERE username='mlopez')";
$query3 = $dbh->prepare($sql3);
$query3->execute();
$data = $query3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$group_id = $data['group_id'];

$miUrl = "welcome.php?user=".$uname."&group=".$group_id;
?>
<form action="<?=$miUrl;?>" method="GET">
..
...

</form>
```

Ahora bien existe unos detalles como que en tu form usas el metodo "**POST**" y estas mandando variables por url que es el equivalente a "**GET**" define cual de los dos usaras.

Te sugiero revisar:

[Metodos Post/Get](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

bien ahora para obtener los valores en tu otra pagina será:

Si es por POST:

```
 $valorObtenido = $_POST["miCampoEnviado"];
```

Si es por GET:

```
  $valorObtenido = $_GET["miCampoEnviado"];
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: muchas gracias ya me funcionó!

Answer (score 0):

no tengo tanta experiencia en PHP pero pareciera ser que a pesar de tener tu form action en POST y los estas esperando efectivamente en POST pero cuando haces esto:

```
welcome.php?user=' . $uname . '&group=' . $group_id
```

en realidad lo estas enviando como GET.

Si lo quieres pasar como POST bastaria con:

```
$uname=$_POST['username'];
```

donde 'username' seria el id de tu input con el que capturas el dato

Comment: No puede ser el id, PHP solicita el name

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es redireccionar de una pagina php a otra y pasar el valor de las variables entre ellas lo puedes hacer de dos formas:

Con la sentencia `header()` de php:

```
header('Location: welcome.php?user=' . $uname . '&group=' . $group_id);
die();
```

o imprimiendo código javascript:

```
echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="welcome.php?user=' . $uname . '&group=' . $group_id'";</script>';
die();
```